# ViewController not responding to touches

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a ViewController in which there is a navigation bar, toolbar and a tableview. I have pinned the navigation bar to top, left and right and fixed the height. I have pinned the toolbar to bottom, left and right and fixed the height. I have pinned the tableview to top, bottom, left and right. Now not even the item bar buttons nor the TableViews respond to touches. I have added a screenshot for the same.I have checked and have added the actions and outlets right.My other views are working perfectly fine.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do other views not respond to touch? Have you tried rebuilding the layout from scratch with a brand new viewcontroller object?

Comment: Yes quite a few times

Comment: are you creating the view in the correct size class? why do you use Any/Regular, not Any/Any?

Comment: Try recreating the view piece by piece but keep a button in the view that when clicked logs to the debugger. After adding which element does the view stop responding?

Comment: It is not responding to any of the buttons. How will the size classes effect?

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided with some code.Once I faced the same problem.Then after some brainstorming I found that the problem was in my code,not view controller.I added some code to find latitude and longitude,turns out that gps kept searching location continuously in the background and for that reason,nothing in view controller responded to touch.